# Open login popup in the browser from Electron Firebase application

Tags: firebase-authentication, electron

I have a web app that uses Firebase for authentication, more specifically it uses the `signInWithPopup(provider)` method. There is also a desktop client based on Electron which simply loads the same web app. With recent updates this method of authentication stopped working as Electron is regarded as unsecure environment.

Is there a way to open the login popup in the default browser (i.e. Chrome) which is secure, complete the login process there, and return to the Electron app with the login information?

Answer (score 1):

If login popup in default browser, the same issue can happen with security. It needs both ends to be secure.

Can you try to generate certificate and use it in your electron ? Instead of self signed certificate, you can generate through Let’s Encrypt (Authorised CA). Hope this solves your issue.